# Trouble accessing textures stored inside a TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY

Tags: opengl, glsl, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to load a texture array into my shader. The issue I'm facing is that I can only draw the last loaded texture in the array. Strangely, this is always at index 0. I create the texture array like so (I'm using Go bindings, but the general idea is clear):

```
// Allocate the array
width := 32
height := 32
var textureArray uint32
gl.GenTextures(1, &textureArray)
gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, textureArray)
gl.TexStorage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, 1, gl.RGBA, width, height, layerCount)
gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)
gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.LINEAR)
gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
gl.TexParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE)

// Load the textures into the array (assume rgbaN.Pix returns an RGBA image
gl.TexSubImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, gl.Ptr(rgba0.Pix))
gl.TexSubImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, 0, 0, 0, 1, width, height, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, gl.Ptr(rgba1.Pix))
gl.TexSubImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, 0, 0, 0, 2, width, height, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, gl.Ptr(rgba2.Pix))
```

Then, inside my draw loop I do:

```
gl.BindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, textureArray)
gl.BindVertexArray(vertexArray)
gl.DrawElements(gl.TRIANGLES, int32(len(indices)), gl.UNSIGNED_INT, nil)
```

My shader looks like this:

```
#version 110
#if GL_EXT_texture_array
#extension GL_EXT_texture_array : enable
#endif

varying vec2 texCoord;

uniform sampler2DArray texArray;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2DArray(texArray, vec3(texCoord, 0.0));
}
```

With this shader, I always draw the last added texture to the array. If I change the `vec3(texCoord, 0.0)` to something like `vec3(texCoord, 1.0)` I get blackness. Nothing is drawn. My current thought is that I'm not assigning the uniform correctly, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: How are you planning on doing 3D textures in ES 2.0?

Comment: @genpfault I think that the `GL_EXT_texture_array` extension enables storing 2D textures inside a texture array. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Not seeing `GL_EXT_texture_array` on the [ES registry extension list](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/index_es.php).

Comment: hmm. I'm kind of new to this. What if the device I'm running this on has ES 3.0? Will these devices support the extension?

Comment: ES 3.0 has `glTexImage3D()` in the base spec so no need for an extension.

Answer (score 0):

The `glTexImage3D()` function creates the *entire* 3D (or 2D array) texture. The `depth` parameter is the depth of the image itself (i.e., the total number of planes in a 2D array).  So when you load the second plane, it replaces the first plane, and when you load the third plane, it replaces the second plane. (It also overruns the array bounds, whoops!)

If you want to load a 3D (or 2D array) texture one plane at a time, use `glTexSubImage3D`.

Comment: Good to know! I changed it to `gl.TexSubImage3D(gl.TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY_EXT, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, <index>, gl.RGBA,
  gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, gl.Ptr(rgbaN.Pix))` but now nothing shows up. Any other leads?

Comment: @Max: Have you carefully read the documentation for `glTexSubImage3D`, including the description of what each of the parameters mean?

Comment: Yes, I did, but it's not that clear. Specifically this part `For two-dimensional array textures, the z index refers to the slice index.`. Does this mean that the z-index should be the offset into the array and the depth should always be 1?

Comment: @Max: Earlier in the paragraph, you'll see that the z indexes go from `zoffset` to `zoffset + depth - 1`.

Comment: I did read that, but I'm still not sure what it means. If I want my texture to occupy a single element `i` of the array, does that mean I should set the zoffset to `i` and a depth offset of 1? I tried doing so but was still not able to draw my textures.

Comment: Yes, `zoffset` should be `i` and `depth` should be 1.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunately nothing is rendering now :(